# How to install Linux 3.2.40 headers on Synology DS214 with DSM 6.1?

Tags: linux-kernel, header-file, synology

Since I'm tired of cross-compiling and already have a working (cross-compiled) `gcc` on my Synology DiskStation DS214 with DSM 6.1, I'd like to install the Linux headers of the Linux version running on the DiskStation into `/usr/include` which is initially empty. There's a [tookkit for developers by Synology](https://sourceforge.net/projects/dsgpl/files/toolkit/armadaxp/), but the headers in `/usr/include` create a `linux/version.h` with `LINUX_VERSION_CODE=132636` which is much lower than 3.2.40 given by `uname -a`. Maybe this is due to the version mismatch of DSM 6.1 and the 5.2 for the toolkit. Downgrading DSM to 5.2 is not an option, maybe impossible.

Running `sudo make headers_install` in the Linux 3.2.40 source on the DiskStation fails due to

```
$ sudo env CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/usr/include" \
CPPFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/usr/include" \
CXXFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/usr/include" \
LDFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16" \
make headers_install \
CFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/usr/include" \
CPPFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/usr/include" \
CXXFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16 -I/usr/include" \
LDFLAGS="-mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=vfpv3-d16" \
INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/usr
  CHK     include/linux/version.h
  HOSTCC  scripts/basic/fixdep
In file included from /opt/toolchain/include/features.h:434:0,
                 from /opt/toolchain/include/sys/types.h:25,
                 from scripts/basic/fixdep.c:106:
/opt/toolchain/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:29: fatal error: gnu/stubs-soft.h: No such file or directory
 # include 
                             ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [scripts/basic/fixdep] Error 1
make: *** [scripts_basic] Error 2
```

Other build setups, like `binutils`, `make`, etc., don't have any problem picking up the `-mfloat-abi` and not including `gnu/stubs-soft.h`. Linux 3.2.86 which is the latest of 3.2.x has the same problem.

I know that there might be an easier way, that the setup is supposed to work primarily with cross-compilation and that there's no use case for what I want to do, but I'd like to understand how things work or why it's impossible to do what I want to do.

Comment: Any updates on this? This issue prevents using containers that do require these headers, like https://sysdig.com/opensource/sysdig/install/